# Can Emmet Be Used to Create FXML?

Tags: scala, javafx, emmet, scalafx

I have a scalaFX  app that currently has its views created programmatically. I am wondering if I can use the Emmet tool to create FXML (particularly ScalaFXML) because I want to recreate my views in ScalaFXML to separate my views from my controllers more effectively. I have searched the internet and cannot find out if this is possible. So far I have only used Emmet for HTML. Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been looking around for something for PrimeFaces; I had trouble finding anything. I guess maybe it's because people who are using it are actually writing "normal" HTML with JS frameworks.

The good news is, it's completely (and easily!) customizable: just find the installation directory, and edit the "snippets.json" file, or create a new one called (for example) `snippets-scalaFX.json`. Mine on a Windows 10 machine, installed as a plugin for NPP, was `C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\plugins\EmmetNPP\emmet\snippets.json`.

It's pretty obvious once you get in there, but inside the "snippets" object just add some more fields for yourself. For example, to make a PrimeFaces `commandButton` tag I added:

`"pc": "p:commandButton"`

You can use `$0` or `${<placeholder text>}` to define tabstops for expanded snippets, and `|` to define the caret starting point.

Full docs on editing snippets are [here](http://docs.emmet.io/customization/snippets/).